# How to capture additional SQL table values with an asp:DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu

SQL Server: I have 3 columns [ID], [Text], [Value]

**ASPX page**:

I have a dopdownlist populated by a `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="Server" DataSourceID="sql" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Text" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql" runat="Server" SelectCommand="sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />
```

Using `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` I can capture 2 of the values in the SQL Server table based on selected value.

**Question**:

How to capture the additional column `[Value]` based on the users #ddl selected value?

Notes:

I can achieve this using javascript to populate a matching dropdown list using the [Value] field instead of the [ID] field and match on [Text] field.

There must be a more efficient and appropriate way to handle this with just asp or VB.

---

**ANSWER USED**

I simply got the value at time of use using the `ddl [ID]` and a sql select statement.

```
SELECT @Value = [Value] FROM [tbl] WHERE [ID] = @ID
```

Passing in @ID as the dropdownlist selectedvalue.

Comment: In what way do you want to "capture" this additional column value?  Are you just hoping to display to the user in a Label?  Do you want to do with or without doing a postback?

Comment: Thanks for the response. When the user selects an option from the dropdownlist I want to pass three values from the selected row to Code Behind. I need all the values to run an insert stored procedure. The value does not need to display on the page I just need the value. A hiddenfield would work but I don't know how to link with the ddl selected value.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Hey I didn't realise it was my Hornets fan. You going to save the day for me again?

Comment: LOL I didn't realize you were the same person as well.  I have an idea for an approach, but it's not very elegant.  I'll post something in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in but found an obvious solution I was missing. I will catch you on the next issue that arises lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the ID is a unique identifier of the row, so why would you need the text or value columns to be submitted by the form? You can just retrieve these from the database using the ID that is submitted. Or am I missing something here?